# How to Specify the structure of the payload and Specify headers in every request Django URLS

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-urls

Below are my urls.py I need to Specify the structure of the payload and Specify headers in every request

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
    from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
    from . import views

    router = DefaultRouter()

    router.register("patient", views.PatientsApiView)

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'', include(router.urls))

     ]
```

**Below are my views.py** 
I have made 1 view with model viewset and the other with the generic API view

```
class PatientsApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Patient
    fields = ("id",  "first_name", "last_name", "phone", "email", "created_at")

"""
Create a serializer in serializer.py

class EmbryoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Embryo
        fields = ("id", "name", "analysis_result", "created_at", "patient")

"""

class EmbryoApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        embryo = Embryo.objects.all()
        serializer = EmbryoSerializer(embryo, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = EmbryoSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        embryo = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = EmbryoSerializer(embryo, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def patch(self, request, user_id):
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        serializer = EmbryoSerializer(embryo, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
router.register("embryo", views.EmbroApiView)
```

How do you think I can achieve this in my views.py

Comment: Use a middleware, or specify them on a case by case basis in your views.

Comment: @spectras Is it possible to achieve this urls.py. I don't have to use routers if I can achieve this in urls.py

Comment: It is not, and it is not what `urls.py` is for. Its purpose is to describe your urls, it should do that and nothing more.

Comment: @spectras I have added my views above. Is it possible to show in code how I can Specify the structure of the payload and Specify headers in every request. I have 2 types of views just in case

Comment: Payload you already do, since serializers will validate it. Headers you can simply pass to `Response()`. For instance `return Response( … , headers={'My-Header': 'hello'})` will add the header.

Comment: @spectras Sorry took a while to figure it I have answered below do you think that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Specifying  the structure of the payload and headers for every request is best done in views.py and serializers.py

Payload will be validated in serializers . Headers you can simply pass to Response(). 
For instance 
`return Response( … , headers={'My-Header': 'hello'})` will add the header.

example:

```
class EmbryoApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        embryo = Embryo.objects.all()
        serializer = EmbryoSerializer(embryo, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, headers={'My-Header': 'Below are all the embroys for this patient'})
```